# Boundary behavior of Harmonic functions 

Tags: cv.complex-variables

Assume that $f$ is harmonic in the unit disk $|z|<1$, with boundary function of bounded variation, such that $$\lim_{r\to 1}f(re^{it})= 0$$ for $t\in[0,\pi]\setminus \mathbf{Q}$, where $\mathbf{Q}$ are rational numbers. Can we then state the following  $$\lim_{r\to 1}f(re^{it})= 0,\ \ \ t\in[0,\pi].  $$

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "boundary function"?

Comment: $f=P[g]$, where $g(t):[0,2\pi]\to \gamma\subset \mathbf{C}$ is of bounded variation. 

Comment: You can use the fact that Fourier series of a function of bounded variation converges everywhere to arithmetic mean of left and right limits.